# Why would there be a spike in coverage within a gene in RNA seq data?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, microbiology

I'm looking at RNA seq data in Geneious for Salmonella typhimurium and I occasionally see a spike in coverage for a sequence of RNA within a gene. Why is there a section of the gene that seems to be transcribed much more often than any other part of it? The name of the gene in question is ftsI which is an essential cell division protein that may link upstream cytoplasmic cell division proteins with downstream periplasmic cell division proteins.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Your question seems potentially acceptatble, however it needs some modification before you are likely to get an answer. In the meantime it risks removal as "unclear what you mean". First, I had no idea what geneious was. You should capitalize proprietary software and state what it is. More important you should include an image of the peak you are seeing and indicate what organism it is. We cannot be expected to know what ftsl is, and CDS is not the name of a gene but an acronym for "coding sequence". Please edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how your libraries have been prepared and sequenced it is hard to tell if that is due to a technical or biological source.

However, there are a few bias sources in RNA-seq (which aren't an issue in DNA-seq)

One of them is that if you used a "random-hexamer" protocol, they're known to not be so random after all. See: [Hansen KD, Brenner SE, Dudoit S. Biases in Illumina transcriptome sequencing caused by random hexamer priming. Nucleic Acids Res. 2010;38: e131.](https://doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkq224)

You might also have a contamination from other species that would present a sequence identity for that part more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Some regions might be more present than others in the sequencing data because some exons might be more often included in the mature transcript (alternative splicing). Check whether the peaks matches with exons. **Edit: This will likely not be the case since you are dealing with a bacteria: as far as I know, splicing is very uncommon in bacteria**

Another likely explanation could be that there are biases during library preparation or sequencing.

In both scenarios, the biases would be post-transcriptional.

Yet another possibility would be that other transcription units are present within your gene of interest. This sometimes happen, especially when dealing with compact genomes.

Comment: Salmonella would not have exons/introns.

Comment: @emilliman5 Indeed, I hadn't taken into account the fact that the poster's question involved a bacteria.